# BridJ - Pointer.pointerToAddress(long peer) has been deprecated

Tags: java, bridj

There is an example called [TaskbarListDemo.java](https://github.com/nativelibs4java/BridJ/blob/master/src/main/demos/TaskbarListDemo.java) in BridJ repo on GitHub. When I try to compile in Netbeans with the [.jar library](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.nativelibs4java/bridj/0.7.0) downloaded from Maven (version 0.7.0), the method `Pointer.pointerToAddress(long peer)` used in this example in line 100 is deprecated.

What is the correct method to use in that case? [The docs](http://nativelibs4java.sourceforge.net/bridj/api/stable/org/bridj/Pointer.html#pointerToAddress-long-) doesn't explain anything about it. There are these options available (doesn't mark as deprecated):

```
public static <P> Pointer<P> pointerToAddress(long peer, PointerIO<P> io)
public static <P> Pointer<P> pointerToAddress(long peer, Class<P> targetClass, Pointer.Releaser releaser)
public static <P> Pointer<P> pointerToAddress(long peer, Type targetType, Pointer.Releaser releaser)
public static Pointer<?> pointerToAddress(long peer, long size, Pointer.Releaser releaser)
public static <P> Pointer<P> pointerToAddress(long peer, long size, PointerIO<P> io, Pointer.Releaser releaser)
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I really don't know if this solution is beautiful, but it works and it solves the "deprecated" issue:

```
Releaser nopReleaser = new Releaser() {
    @Override
    public void release(Pointer<?> pointer) {
        // NOP
    }
};
hwnd = Pointer.pointerToAddress(hwndVal, Integer.class, nopReleaser);
```